# getting following error whiling running npm install -g create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

when i tried to run npm install -g create-react-app  to create react app getting following error.
when i tired to run "npm install -g npm" getting same error.

Could you please guide me solve this issue ?

debug.log file,

````
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.1
4 verbose npm-session 5c7b621106479737
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-react-app@latest error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 162ms
10 verbose stack Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
10 verbose stack     at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:149:17)
10 verbose stack     at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1597:48)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createConnection (https.js:137:22)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\_http_agent.js:265:26)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\agent.js:77:11)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.addRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\_http_agent.js:239:10)
10 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:305:16)
10 verbose stack     at request (https.js:333:10)
10 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:54:17
10 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
10 verbose stack     at fetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:41:10)
10 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:332:14
10 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-retry\index.js:29:24
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\user\development
12 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
13 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "create-react-app"
14 verbose node v14.17.1
15 verbose npm  v6.14.13
16 error code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
17 error error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]```
````

Comment: Please follow the document, it specifically mentions to use `npx` not `npm` while using cra. https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

Use the below commands to set up the development environment.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Always follow the [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) :)